# C# Fazer select e exibir em um combobox

Tags: c#, sql, .net

Estou criando uma aplicação em C# windows Form e queria saber como faço um select de uma tabela e exibi uma lista de clientes em uma combobox.

Comment: Pro favor, dê mais detalhes do que deseja. O que você já tentou e qual a dúvida específica?

Comment: Eu quero como seto os valores do meu select feito pelo sqlCommand em um combobox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo esse layout de Tabela em um Banco [SQL Server](http://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/server-cloud/products/sql-server/#fbid=gnXx_GGF8cz):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

1 - *Com* [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx):

```
public DataTable GetUF()
{
    DataTable dataUf = new DataTable("UF");
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha"))
    using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UFID, SIGLA FROM UF ORDER BY SIGLA", Connection))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        dataUf.Load(Command.ExecuteReader());
    }
    return dataUf;
}
```

---

Carregando os dados do DataTable para o [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *CmbUF*

```
CmbUF.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
CmbUF.DataSource = GetUF();
CmbUF.ValueMember = "UFID";
CmbUF.DisplayMember = "SIGLA";
CmbUF.Update();
```

---

2 - Com `Classe` `UF` e [IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

Crie um classe que representa os dados que serviram de modelo para carregar o ComboBox.

```
public class UF
{
        public int UFID { get; set; }
        public String SIGLA { get; set; }
}
```

---

Carregando os dados no `IEnumerable<UF>`

```
public IEnumerable<UF> GetUF()
{
    using (SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=Db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=senha"))
    using (SqlCommand Command = new SqlCommand("SELECT UFID, SIGLA FROM UF ORDER BY SIGLA", Connection))
    {
        Connection.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader Reader = Command.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if (Reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    yield return new UF()
                    {
                        UFID = Reader.GetInt32(0),
                        SIGLA = Reader.GetString(1)
                    };
                }
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

---

Carregando os dados do `IEnumerable<UF>` para o [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *CmbUF*

```
CmbUF.DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;
CmbUF.DataSource = GetUF().ToArray();
CmbUF.ValueMember = "UFID";
CmbUF.DisplayMember = "SIGLA";
CmbUF.Update();
```

**Obs:** percebe que agora o `GetUF()` deve chamar o `ToArray()`, porque o *DataSource* precisa de uma [IList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.collections.ilist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) ou [IListSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.ilistsource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (Arrays, Enumeração, DataTable, DataSet) para carregar !!!

Explicação rápida do que foi utilizado no [ComboBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.controls.combobox%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
CmbUF.DataSource = "FONTE DE DADOS (DATATABLE, DATASET, ILIST, etc)";
CmbUF.ValueMember = "NOME DO CAMPO QUE REPRESENTA A IDENTIFICAÇÃO DE CADA ITEM DO COMBOBOX";
CmbUF.DisplayMember = "TEXTO QUE SERÁ MOSTRADO NO COMBOBOX";            

var c = CmbUF.SelectedValue; //RECUPERANDO O VALOR DA UFID
```